# Creating regexp for conditional matching of ['Cat '(optional) Dog (.*?)] | ['Cat '(optional) (.*?) Dog]

Tags: regex

I need to construct this type of regex.

For example, I have these variations of the string:

> - 'Cat Dog mystring'
> - 'Cat mystring Dog'
> - 'mystring Dog'

And I should always extract 'mystring' from here. How do I handle it?

I tried to use OR matching but it seems a bit too conflict'y here =\

Comment: Maybe `\b(?!(?:Cat|Dog)\b)\w+`? Is `mystring` a single word?

Answer (score 0):

`^(?:Cat )?(?:Dog )?(.*?)(?: Dog)?$` will extract your string (whatever it may be) from your specific examples.

- `^ $` Between start and end of string...
- `(?:Cat )?` Match `Cat` (optional)
- `(?:Dog )?` Match `Dog` (optional)
- `(.*?)` Capture your string
- `(?: Dog)?` Match `Dog` (optional)

[Try it here!](https://regex101.com/r/36l90K/1)